# OpenCV stitching result's dimensions isn't stable

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I am using OpenCV to make panorama.
But the result's dimensions aren't stable and whole stitching isn't stable.
Everytime I get different results.
Can somebody help me to understand what is the reason, or what part os the stitching pipeline isn't stable?
I am doing the most simple version of stitching, using stitch function.
Thank you.

Comment: You should avoid to re-post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610995/opencv-sticther-class-returned-image-size-isnt-stable) multiple times. Once you earn some reputation, you can put a bounty on your question to get more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stitching relies on RANSAC algorithm and it has some degree of randomness (in fact RANSAC stands for Random sample consensus), its results are not stable.

I would pre-seed the random generator before any stitching operation to make the results repeatables.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Answer (score 0):

*Without seeing your images this is a stab in the dark*

Stitching consists of:

- Finding keypoints
- Matching keypoints by calculating distance between its corresponding descriptors
- Some outlier detection process like RANSAC
- Once you get matched keypoints, get homography. To get homography, you should at least have 8 pairs of matched keypoints. In
  reality, you may require more, since some outliers may not get
  removed.

The likelyhood is that somewhere in this process it is finding different keypoints in your image and calculating different distances and therefore different homography.

I would suggest trying the [OpenCV Stitching example pictures](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp) and see if you get a similar response.

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Comment: I have thought that reason can be  a warping algorithms, but checked, OpenCV source handle singular points, now I don't know what can cause the problem.

Comment: For example I am using images from this post : http://www.janeriksolem.net/2012/06/simple-panoramas-with-opencv.html